# Android append text to the top of the textview

Tags: java, android

I have a textview and have currently had all appended information added appear at the bottom of the textview.

```
tv.append("Text " + newNumber + "\n");
```

For example, the textview would, every three seconds, add the next line below the previous:

"Text One\n"

"Text Two\n"

"Text Three\n"

I would like to know if I can have the appended text added to the top of the text view:

"Text Three\n"

"Text Two\n"

"Text One\n"

Comment: use StringBuilder for appending.

Comment: `tv.setText("Text " + newNumber + "\n" + tv.getText().toString())`

Comment: Andrew - that worked perfectly!! Thanks